# Session variables disapear

Tags: c#, oauth, asp.net-mvc-4, session-variables

I have an MVC 4 web app written in C# where I'm setting a session variable, redirecting to the to another website which calls back to my web app (I'm doing the OAuth handshake and placing the temp token in my session) and when the redirect hits my web app I attempt to get my object from the session but it's empty.

Is there a strategy for doing something like this?

I can post my code but it's complicated so let's see what kind of responses I get first.

Please post example strategy code, asp.net/c# are new to me.

Yes, I know that there are OAuth examples included with mvc 4 but I can't use them.

Comment: Why can't you use the methods used by the OAuth examples?  You will find people will be more likely to help you if you give them a reason for ignoring the most straight forward approach.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me how your process works exactly.  When you say "redirecting to another website which calls back to my web app" do you mean the remote website calls your app?  Or that the user is redirected back to your site (which I assume has some token on the querystring?)

There are lots of good examples of how to use OAuth, but if you refuse to follow the typical methods, it will be a lot more difficult.

You need to provide more information on how your handshake works.

Without knowing more, all I can do is guess, in that a new session is being created because something is different about your callback request.  You need to figure out what that is.

Answer (score 0):

small work around would be, which i did in the past is send the session variable value in the query string, and when they redirect you can read the value again, This would be ideal if you are controlling both the sides.